# Headless LibreOffice: How to split an Office document to multiple one-page documents?

Tags: libreoffice

I have a lot of documents in MS Office formats: DOCX, PPTX. And I want to split each of them to multiple one-page documents.

Is it possible in LibreOffice headless mode?